# How can I use wait/notify to make these threads work alternatively?

Tags: java, multithreading, wait, notify

I would like to understand how to make two threads suspend eachother at the right time, I tried looking into documentation and stuff but didn't understand enough; I wanted to make a program like:

ThreadA writes one `int` at a time inside ThreadB as an attribute, then B prints it. 
A waits to write another `int` until it gets confirmation from B that the previous one was printed, and B must wait that A wrote the `int` before printing.

If I were to use `A/B.suspend()` and `A/B.resume()` the situation would be more clear, but I don't understand how to do the same things with `wait` and `notify`.

Here is an example (not working) of what I did:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object lock=new Object();
        ThreadB tB=new ThreadB(lock);
        tB.start();
        ThreadA tA=new ThreadA(lock);
        tA.start();
    }
}
```

ThreadA:

```
public class ThreadA extends Thread {
    private Object lock;
    private ThreadB threadB;
    public ThreadA(Object b,ThreadB tb) {
        lock=b;
        threadB=tb;
    }
    public void run() {
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
                threadB.setI(i);
                synchronized(lock) { //(try/catch omitted for shortness)
                    lock.notify();  //to tell B the int was loaded
                    lock.wait();    //to stop until B tells me that the int has been used
                }   
        }
        //join or something for B
    }   
}
```

Thread B:

```
public class ThreadB extends Thread {
    private Object lock;
    int i;
    public ThreadB(Object b) {
        lock=b;
    }
    public void setI(int x) {
        i=x;
    }
    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            synchronized(lock) { //(try/catch omitted for shortness)
                lock.wait();    //to wait until A loaded the int
            }
            int a=i;
            System.out.println(a);
            synchronized(lock) {
                lock.notify();  //to tell A it can load the next int    
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

I was thinking to use `lock` as a token but I think it's not enough, for example it could happen that A calls `notify` for B and then B proceeds up to notifying A, but A didn't even wait yet..

Comment: You should use something like an actual lock. You should probably use notifyAll instead of notify. Also, spurious wakeups can occur, so you need to actually resume when released, not just when a 'wait' has been notified. [ReentrantLock](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html) might be what you're looking for? Also, you are correct about your race condition.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider to use a shared flag to decide when each thread can access the variable.
See this example: [processor.java](https://github.com/robertorobles/udemy-java_multithreading/blob/master/Thread9/src/demo1/Processor.java)
Each method (produce and consume) is executed independently in its own thread (see [app.java](https://github.com/robertorobles/udemy-java_multithreading/blob/master/Thread9/src/demo1/App.java)).

They use the size of the list to decide whether they can access the list or not.

Hope it helps